# Preserve old docker-compose containers untill next are ready

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-deployment

I am deploying my app via docker-compose, that have 2 services: server app and nginx.

So in CI I created following script of instructions:

```
docker-compose build # create new containers
docker-compose down # down old containers
docker-compose up -d # up new containers
```

But server app container has its own start up time, so right after app start I see 502 page, because server app is not yet ready to receive calls, but nginx is ready.

What I want to do is to preserve old containers running, during that build and up new containers, wait some time for server app to be ready and then somehow substitute them. So whole operation whould be seamless for users.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you looking at Zero downtime deployment module? https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html where service is getting the updates without notice. if yes then you need to use Blue Green deployment module.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with docker-compose. But, yes it is possible with container orchestration tools like **Kubernetes**, the popular orchestration tools.

From [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io) official site :

> **Automated rollouts and rollbacks**
>
> Kubernetes progressively rolls out changes to your application or its
> configuration, while monitoring application health to ensure it
> doesn't kill all your instances at the same time. If something goes
> wrong, Kubernetes will rollback the change for you. Take advantage of
> a growing ecosystem of deployment solutions.
>
> **Self-healing**
>
> Restarts containers that fail, replaces and reschedules containers
> when nodes die, kills containers that don't respond to your
> user-defined health check, and doesn't advertise them to clients until
> they are ready to serve.